# How to connect to rexster server over rexpro within the java code?

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop, rexster, tinkerpop-blueprint

I have a rexster server running locally on my machine on port 8984. I want to connect to my graph dadabase (orientdb) and execute gremlin scripts within my java code. I couldn't find any good example or tutorial on doing that.

Here is my code:

```
import com.tinkerpop.rexster;
import com.tinkerpop.rexster.*;

public class Orient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RexsterClient client = RexsterClientFactory.open("localhost", 8984);
        String script = String.format("g=rexster.getGraph('%s');g.v('%s').map", "test_test", "9:6267");
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = client.execute(script);
        Map<String, Object> map = results.get(0);
        System.out.println(map.get("name"));
    }

}
```

when I try to compile my code like :

```
$javac -cp rexster-protocol-2.6.0.jar Orient.java
```

I get this :

```
Orient.java:1: error: package com.tinkerpop does not exist
import com.tinkerpop.rexster;
                    ^
Orient.java:2: error: package com.tinkerpop.rexster does not exist
import com.tinkerpop.rexster.*;
^
Orient.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        RexsterClient client = RexsterClientFactory.open("localhost", 8984);
        ^
  symbol:   class RexsterClient
  location: class Orient
```

what am I doing wrong? where can I get the dependencies (.jar) files. if any needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all dependent jar files in classpath to compile

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tinkerpop.rexster/rexster-protocol/2.6.0

You would better use maven or gradle build tool rather downloading all the jar files and typing compile command manually.